# gRPC and ASP Net Core: using SslCredentials with non-null arguments is not supported by GrpcChannel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc

I am trying to connect from a client to the service. The service is configurated to use a self signed Ssl certificate and I am trying to configurate the client with the client certificate. I am using this code:

```
string cacert = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("certificados/ca.crt");
string cert = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("certificados/client.crt");
string key = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("certificados/client.key");

KeyCertificatePair keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(cert, key);
SslCredentials sslCreds = new SslCredentials(cacert, keypair);

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://x.x.x.x:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions { Credentials = sslCreds });
var client = new Gestor.GestorClient(channel);
```

But I am getting the following error: using SslCredentials with non-null arguments is not supported by GrpcChannel.

I don't understand very good the message error. SslCredentials is ChannelCredentials? type, and SslCreds is Grpc.Core.SslCredentials. It can be compiled, so the type I guess it is correct.

What I would like to know it is how I can configure the client to use the self signed certificate that I have created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SslCredentials support in only available grpc-dotnet is to provide some level of compatibility with Grpc.Core in the most common use case, it doesn't expose all the functionality though. In grpc-dotnet, only SslCredentials() (parameterless which uses the default roots) is supported. If you want to provide your self-signed creds, you can certainly do that, you'll need to use a different API for configuring GrpcChannel:

See example here (creating a GrpcChannel with custom credentials).
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/dd72d6a38ab2984fd224aa8ed53686dc0153b9da/testassets/InteropTestsClient/InteropClient.cs#L170

Comment: +1. **Basically**: Extract the base64 data portion from the PEM cert file, and decode it to get the original bytes. Then build a `X509Certificate2` cert-object using these bytes. Create a new `HttpClientHandler` handler, and set its validator to `DangerousAcceptAny...`. Then add the cert-object to this handler as a client cert. Finally, create a new `HttpClient` using this handler and integrate it into a (newly created or pre-existing) `GrpcChannelOptions` channel options object. Feed this channel options object into the `GrpcChannel.ForAddress()` function to create a new channel. *Phew!*

Answer (score 4):

I spend a fair bit of time googling around for solutions to this problem, and didn't find a concise answer. Here is ultimately how I was able to configure a dotnet client to use mutual SSL authentication:

```
MyService.MyServiceClient GetClient(){
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

    // Validate the server certificate with the root CA
    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, _) => {
        chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
        chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(new X509Certificate2("ca.crt"));
        return chain.Build(cert);
    };

    // Pass the client certificate so the server can authenticate the client
    var clientCert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile("client.crt", "client.key");
    httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

    // Create a GRPC Channel
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:8080", new GrpcChannelOptions{
        HttpClient = httpClient,
    });
    
    return new MyService.MyServiceClient(channel);
}
```